# Gradient of marginal likelihood of Gaussian Process w.r.t likelihood parameters with Laplace approximation

Tags: derivatives

The derivation of gradient of the marginal likelihood w.r.t covariance function hyperparameters $\theta$ is given in http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW5.pdf, page 125. However, the gradient w.r.t likelihood parameters (let's call them $\sigma$) is not derived.

I found the final equations for this gradient w.r.t $\sigma$ in the source code of the [GPML](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/) toolbox by the book's authors and the [GPStuff](https://research.cs.aalto.fi/pml/software/gpstuff/) toolbox, as well as in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3c1f/3b070646a7e2bff262e342d715ed4c68c4e3.pdf). However, I found no derivation. The equations are similar to those of the gradient w.r.t the covariance function hyperparameters $\theta$. But I don't understand how $\frac{\partial \hat{f}}{\partial \sigma}$ is derived (supposedly similar to $\frac{\partial \hat{f}}{\partial \theta}$ in Eq. (5.24) of the GPML book). The abovementioned paper (Eq. (18)) and the source code of both GPML and GPstuff all use the equation:
$$\frac{\partial \hat{f}}{\partial \sigma} = (I + K W)^{-1} K \frac{\partial}{\partial \sigma} \nabla \log p(y | \hat{f}) \text.$$
I tried but could not figure out how to derive this same equation.

Any reference or hint to derive this equation is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: wow, I've been looking for these gradients, thank you so much for giving such a great reference! Google showed it as first! :-)